# PowerShell - need ini file for consecutive numbering

Tags: file, powershell, configuration

I'm currently working on a script for automation. This script should have a global count variable that does not reset itself when the script is executed again. Therefore, I need a configuration file that stores this count variable and uses it when it is called up again. This counting variable is also dependent on an ID. There is therefore a count variable for each ID. The configuration file can be in XML or INI format.  Can someone tell me how to create such a file the easiest way and how to add IDs or get the count variable?  I dont think "csv-import/export" is the right way.

I've already tried this...

```
$results = @()
$details = @{
    Key1 = $ID
    Key2 = $count
    Key3 = "sth"
    Key4 = "sth"
    Key5 = "sth"
    }

$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
$results | export-csv -Path C:\Users\...\configure.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Unfortunately, I can't get any further here, because it overwrites the previous entry every time the ID changes and I don't know how to add additional entries (if the ID already exists), update entries (count variable) and call this count variable to use it in Powershell.

Anybody got a suggestion?

Best Regards

Comment: you can use it in a function and make it a constant so that the value is only changed by the function

Comment: Why not use a registry key for keeping track of this?  Assuming it's unique per user.

Comment: You could use a text file to keep the value in, or store it in a database.

Comment: I want to avoid using a database if possible. Is there no easy way to use an XML file that gives me the count variable and which I can easily update with a command? :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-5.1), [`Export-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-5.1) and [`Import-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml?view=powershell-5.1) to save and load you ID counts to a XML file:

```
$xmlFilePath = 'idCounts.xml'

# If the XML file exists, it is loaded
if( Test-Path -Path $xmlFilePath -PathType Leaf )
{
    $hashTable = Import-Clixml -Path $xmlFilePath
}
# Else a new hash table is initialized
else
{
    $hashTable = @{}
}

# Set the count of ID '001' to 1
$hashTable['001'] = 1

# Increment the count of ID '002'
$hashTable['002'] += 1

# Save the hash table to the XML file
$hashTable | Export-Clixml -Path $xmlFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the tips. In the end, I managed it myself in the following way:

```
if(!((import-csv "C:\Users\...\Desktop\ini.txt") | where-object {$_.Key1 -eq $ID}))
{
$results = @()

$details = @{
    Key 1 = $ID
    Key 2 = 1
    Key 3 = "something"
    Key 4 = "something"
    Key 5 = "something"
    Key 6 = "something"
    }

$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
$results | export-csv -Path C:\Users\...\Desktop\ini.txt -append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

The system first checks whether there is an entry with the corresponding ID. If not, an object is created that has that ID. The count variable is set to 1 when it is newly created. The entry is attached to the file with "Export CSV".

```
$select = (import-csv "C:\Users\...\Desktop\ini.txt" | where{$_.Key1 -eq $ID})
[int]$global:number = [convert]::ToInt32($select.Key2)
```

To use the count variable, the configuration file is imported. I have set it to "global" because it has to operate over several functions.

```
($csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\...\Desktop\ini.txt") | ForEach {
    if ($_.Key1 -eq $ID) {
        $_.Key2 = $global:number}
}

$csv | Export-Csv "C:\Users\...\Desktop\ini.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

At the end, the count variable is updated and transferred back to the file with "Export CSV".

Nevertheless thank you for all the interesting suggestions!

Best Regards